# If the subject doesn't equal to then it is not defined

Tags: python

Sorry for the title because i am not sure what it should be. I was given this task where i had to select two subject from the list and add the price up and my codes are:

```
print("choose two subjects")
print("English $100")
print("Math $75")
print("Science $125")
print("Stem $200")
a = input("Choose two subjects: ")
a = a.split()
for x in a:
  x = x.lower()
  print(x)
  if x == "english":
    eng = 100
  elif x is not "english":
    eng = int(0)

  elif x == "science":
    sci = 125
  elif x is not "science":
    sci = int(0)

  elif x == "stem":
    stem = 200
  elif x is not "stem":
    stem = int(0)

  elif x == "math":
    math = 100
  elif x is not "math":
    math = int(0)
print(eng + sci + math + stem)
```

i have an error when i type in english and science which outputs "math" is not defined

Comment: Can you provide the input you're typing?

Comment: Outside the for loop set all the values to 0 (`math`, `eng`, etc)

Comment: Choose two subjects: scinece and english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making things a bit tidier:

```
a = input("Choose two subjects: ")
a = a.split()

# define the prices here
prices = {'english': 100, 'science': 125, 'stem': 200, 'math': 100}

# using list comprehension. What his means:
# for all courses in the input, return me their value from the prices-dict
# and then sum them up
cost = sum(prices[course.lower()] for course in a)

print(cost)
```

Comment: What you lose in this method are the *scores* (and subject-score combinations) that contributed to the end result. Trivially fixed, of course, but worth mentioning.

Comment: is it possible if can make a diagram of what you did.

Comment: @jpp True. I didn't see it as a requirement in the question though so I focused on the result.

Comment: @DevPatel What do you mean by a diagram?

Comment: I mean, is it possible if you can show me the flow chart of your codes.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Can you show me an example?

Comment: An example of flow chart diagram is on https://www.programiz.com/article/flowchart-programming @BramVanroy

Comment: Sorry  not going to do that. The comments should explain the code well enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define then first by assigning some value, for example you can do this:

```
eng = 0
sci = 0
math = 0
stem = 0
```

and then the rest of your code:

```
print("choose two subjects")
print("English $100")
print("Math $75")
print("Science $125")
print("Stem $200")
a = input("Choose two subjects: ")
a = a.split()
for x in a:
  x = x.lower()
  print(x)
  if x == "english":
    eng = 100
  elif x is not "english":
    eng = int(0)

  elif x == "science":
    sci = 125
  elif x is not "science":
    sci = int(0)

  elif x == "stem":
    stem = 200
  elif x is not "stem":
    stem = int(0)

  elif x == "math":
    math = 100
  elif x is not "math":
    math = int(0)
print(eng + sci + math + stem)
```

Comment: I'll elaborate on this in saying that with the `elif x == "math"` and `elif x is not "math"`, neither of those if statements are evaluating to true. This means `math` is never created, thus giving the `"math" is not defined` error.

Comment: I don't understand why this gets upvoted. Initial declaration of the variables is indeed a problem, but there's a lot else that's wrong: using `is` for string comparison, using `elif` instead of `if` so that some case will never be reached. E.g. stem and math will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You do not define certain variables and therefore  cannot access them.

**Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables**

This is a way you can simplify your logic:

```
a = input("Choose two subjects: ")
# english science

a = a.split()

mapper = {'english': 100, 'science': 125, 'stem': 200, 'math': 100}
d = {}

for x in a:
    x = x.lower()
    d[x] = mapper[x]

print(d)
# {'english': 100, 'science': 125}

print(sum(d.values()))
# 225
```